# Priority column selection until rolling cell values =0 then swtich to next priority column etc

Tags: excel

I need to take subtract a cell value away from another cell based on a priority column until priority column =0. Q1. How do I firstly choose the correct priority cell and then switch to next priority when value reduces to 0? It is for a cash flow sheet. At present I have 3 priority columns and they will reduce by the value column if negative until zero then switch to another column based on priority.....Is this possible?

I have 4 columns. Column A - Showing negative values. Column B, C and D with values increasing by a rate of return. If Column A, B or C is priority 1, then the negative value needs to be taken from the value in the corresponding cell. This continues until the priority column is zero. When this happens, the negative in column A needs to start taking from priority 2 column and so on...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, from your public profile, I see you have not taken the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), I suggest you do so and also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can then come back and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52763039/edit) to give it more clarity and help us to help you

Comment: Without an example of how your data is currently laid out, this question is not answerable.